# what kind of gematria systems are there in chinese?

Tags: characters, history

Since in **Chinese culture** there is a lot of materials about *astronomy* and *supernatural* methods so I'm interested to know about **Gematria** as it exists in most languages...

Like this:

[Gematria Calculator](http://www.gematrix.org/)

Comment: Did you mean [Gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) itself or more generally, Gematria-like system?

Comment: everything Gematria-like system

Comment: Then Chinese have a stroke counting system for Chinese characters when choosing a name. That's *supernatural*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for similar Chinese Numerology, here's some useful [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Chinese_culture) which describe the meaning of different numbers in Chinese culture. I would not define it as a classical Gematria system, but that's the only thing in my mind now.

Answer (score 2):

I know you can calculate Gematria on UTF8 (Hence Unicode and all the chars) using the Online Gimatria Calculator http://www.gematrix.org - it worked for me in Hebrew too: http://www.c2kb.com/gematria - Hope it was help full.

Answer (score 1):

Try the site: biblenumbers.atwebpages.com

Chinese gematria following a pattern similar to the Greek and Hebrew can be found at the web pages listed below.

This is based on the traditional Chinese using the Big5 character set. The first character "one" is given the number 1, and so on through all the Chinese characters. Since Big5 is set up with "gaps" between blocks of characters, the numbers jump accordingly just like the Greek and Hebrew, but not by increasing powers of ten.

You can find the explanation of the Chinese gematria system here:
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/data/schema.htm#chinese

A Chinese character gematria convertor is on this page:
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/convertor.htm

Complete gematria studies of a few Bible passages are listed below.

Exodus 34:6-7
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/proclamation_in_chinese.htm

Genesis 1:1
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/genesis_1_1_chinese.htm

John 1:1
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/john_1_1_chinese.htm

Revelation 1:8
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/revelation_1_8_chinese.htm

Revelation 21:6 & 22:13
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/rev_22_13_chinese.htm

Revelation (the entire vision)
http://biblenumbers.atwebpages.com/chinese/revelation_chinese.htm

Comment: did you just try to edit your answer?

Comment: What you're talking about is concordance, not gematria